# Is there a way to see what variables are declared inside of a method?

Tags: objective-c, variables, tweak, theos

Im making a tweak in theos, and need to see the names of some variables.

Say a method looks like this:

```
- (UILabel*)makeALabel {
    UILabel *name_that_i_want = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [name_that_i_want setText:@"abcdefg"];
    return name_that_i_want;
}
```

When I look through the headers for this method, I would see:

```
-(id)makeALabel;
```

Is there a way for me to dump the variables that get declared inside of that method when I hook into it?

```
-(id)makeALabel {
    %orig;
    //somehow get name of the label declared
    UILabel *label = MSHookIvar<UILabel *>(self, "name_that_i_want");
}
```

Comment: I seriously doubt it.  Local variables are optimized by the compiler and may not even "exist" as distinct entities.

Comment: Why do you think you need to see the names of locals?

Answer (score 1):

No!

Needing to know values of variables declared within a function or methods or object is indicative of **bad design**.  It goes against *encapsulation* one of the 3 main principles of object-oriented programming.

Comment: And besides that it will rot your teeth.

Comment: @Hot I'm sorry... I don't get it.  I'm afraid I also don't know if you're laughing at my answer or with me (what are we laughing at?).  If it's the former and you think my answer is misplaced -- it very well could be -- I'd prefer you let me know directly.  :)

Comment: Oh, I just get a little burr under my saddle when people go off on encapsulation, et al.  Encapsulation certainly has its place (and a very important place), but there are definitely times when it should be tossed out the window.  But in this case the OP is asking for something that probably doesn't make sense (ie, it's not one of those definite times), and he likely needs a little "help" understanding this.  (So the answer is both.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO**.

What you are trying to do, may be accomplished by changing the design of your requirement, by creating a Class and ivars that you can use in the methods, just to replace the local variables.

Then you can use `Objective-C Runtime` to access ivars/properties/methods of a Class.